# Android Google sign in stuck in loop

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-plus, google-play-services

I am implementing a Google plus sign in from a `Fragment`.
I am getting an Infinite loop of the Google sign in my dialog.

Code:
Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    Log.e("TEST", "requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode);
    if (FragmentLogIn.RC_SIGN_IN == requestCode){
        FragmentLogIn fragment = (FragmentLogIn)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(mainContent.getId());
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent)
{           
    Log.e("GOOGLE+", "requestCode: " + requestCode + "responseCode = " + responseCode);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    Log.e("GOOGLE TEST", "onConnected");
    //get user info
    try{
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(email);
        } else {
            Log.e("GOOGLE+", "info = null");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mSignInClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{
    Log.e("GOOGLE TEST", "onConnectionSuspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), getActivity(),
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if (view.getId() == R.id.google_sign_in_button) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.google_sign_out_button) {
        revokeGplusAccess();

    }
}

private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        Log.e("accountName", accountName);
        String scopes = "oauth2:profile "+Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;;
        String token = null;
        try {
            if (getActivity() != null)
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GOOGLE+", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 1);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e("GOOGLE+", e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.d("TOKEN", "token: " + s);
    }
}

private void revokeGplusAccess() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                Log.e("GOOGLE+", "User access revoked!");
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

This code works when it's written in an `Activity`but when I switched it to a `Fragment` I get an infinite loop. 
What I'm doing wrong? Does any body have a different example of login with Google plus using an access token?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: should i add any log calls?

Comment: this is what i get:


08-20 16:02:43.923: E/GOOGLE TEST(28215): onConnected
08-20 16:02:43.931: E/accountName(28215): ***@gmail.com
08-20 16:02:44.861: D/TOKEN(28215): token: null
08-20 16:02:46.220: E/GOOGLE TEST(28215): onConnected
08-20 16:02:46.220: E/accountName(28215): ***@gmail.com
08-20 16:02:47.150: D/TOKEN(28215): token: null
08-20 16:02:48.978: E/GOOGLE TEST(28215): onConnected
08-20 16:02:48.986: E/accountName(28215): ***@gmail.com
08-20 16:02:49.970: D/TOKEN(28215): token: null

Answer (score 4):

The infinite loop problem comes when you disconnect the `googleApiClient` in `onStop()`. You should do that only in `onDestroy()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works. Thank you so much. I spent ages trying to fix this.

Comment: @gellyke i am also stuck in sign in, can you help me too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908346/android-google-sign-in-googleapiclient-connect

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
if (mSignInClicked) {
        // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
        // resolve all
        // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
        resolveSignInError();
    }
```

from `onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)` method and the infinite loop wont happen anymore.